# highcharts how to "cut" a certain date period

Tags: highcharts

I am drawing a stock profit chart. 
I am collecting data in the stock exchange trading hours. 
over a period of a few days I want to display the graph **only** in the trading hour

[image]

There are no data for in between trades but due to weekends and after trading hours, 
you can bearly see the graph on the desired range.

the js code is :

```
$.each(data.profits, function (index, value)
  {
   if (value.y != ""){
      profits.push([(new Date(value.x)).getTime(), parseFloat(value.y)]);
   }
  });
```

where
    `value.x` - unix timestamp in milliseconds
and `value.y` - profit

is there a setting for highcharts to ignore time range, somthing like:

```
xAxis:
   {
      dontdisplay: weekends and after trades hour!
    },
```

Comment: Can you show us some code what you already have up to now? Will be easier to help you then :)

Comment: hi @j0nes, thanks for the quick response, I have edited the question to make it more understanable

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts there is no option like this, but you can ignore the weekends in your code.

For example:

```
$.each(data.profits, function (index, value) {
    var date = new Date(value.x);
    var dayOfWeek = date.getDay(); // Sunday is 0, Monday is 1, and so on.
    var hours = date.getHours(); // From 0 to 23.

    if (value.y != "" && dayOfWeek != 0 && dayOfWeek != 6 && hours > 7 && hours < 19) {
        profits.push([date.getTime(), parseFloat(value.y)]);
    }
});
```

So, you'll get only points which has been collected between monday to friday, from 8:00 to 18:00.